# Response.Redirect and IFrames

Tags: asp.net

I have a Main.aspx page and a Sub.aspx page.

The Sub.aspx page resides in my Main.aspx page via IFrame.  So the IFrame contains / loads the Sub.aspx

In another Third.aspx completely unrelated I've got some code that needs to redirect back to Main.aspx but then there are some querystrings that need to be passed to Sub.aspx (or put antoher way my Sub.aspx needs to get those values from the Main.aspx).

My Sub.aspx will check for that querystring flag and if set, run x JS scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe pass the QueryString values to Main and, in its Page_Load, include them in the src for the iframe?  You can [use the iframe like a server control](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37635.aspx) to do this.

Comment: ah, so you can access it via the IFrame's src

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Yup.  Also, quick side note... if you accept this answer, do so while it's zero-score.  I'm close to an Unsung Hero badge :)